# Generating hex file using gcc

Tags: c, gcc, hex

I have a small C function and I want to make a hex file for it.

Running

```
gcc -c in.c
```

makes an object file But I need hex file for this standalone function.
I need to put this on a separate location, so that I can simply JMP to this location from my main code. But I want this to be in hex format.

I cant do a -

```
gcc -c in.c -o in.hex
```

This is not working..
Please help me out..

Comment: try this  objcopy --change-address 0xE0000 -O ihex test.o test.hex

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By using `objcopy` we can make hex file

```
gcc -c example.c

objcopy --change-address 0xE0000 -O ihex example.o example.hex
```

it will generate `example.hex` file

use `Bless Hex Editor` to see the .hex file clearly

Comment: Funny.... He never asked about an address. Yet you and cyberworm both show the exact same example. Almost like you both saw it somewhere.... Hmm.

Answer (score 5):

First you need to use the linker [`ld`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/) to create a raw binary binary file. Then use [`objcopy`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html) to create the hex file.

Comment: haven't used objcopy before. +1